# Caching functions in Aiohttp-Asyncio

Tags: python, caching, memcached, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I'm trying to cache a function from aiohttp using memcached. Caching I want to do as a decorator. 
An example of calling the decorator looks like this:

```
@cache("main_page", expire=25)
@asyncio.coroutine
def page(request):
    return aiohttp_jinja2.render_template('index', request, {} )
```

The function decorator which deals with caching looks like this:

```
def cache_key(name, kwargs):
    key = b'\xff'.join(bytes(k, 'utf-8') + b'\xff' + pickle.dumps(v) for k, v in kwargs.items())
    key = bytes(hashlib.sha1(key).hexdigest(), 'ascii')
    return key


def cache(name, expire=0):
    def decorator(func):
        @asyncio.coroutine
        def wrapper(request=None, **kwargs):
            assert isinstance(request, (aiohttp.web_reqrep.Request, type(None))), type(request)
            args = [r for r in [request] if isinstance(r, aiohttp.web_reqrep.Request)]
            assert isinstance(mc, aiomcache.Client)
            key = cache_key(name, kwargs)
            value = yield from mc.get(key)
            if value is None:
                value = yield from func(*args, **kwargs)
                yield from mc.set(key, pickle.dumps(value,   protocol=pickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL), exptime=expire)
            else:
                value = pickle.loads(value)
            print(value)
            return value

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```

But I get error in console:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/aiohttp_debugtoolbar/panels/headers.py", line 25, in process_response
    sorted(response.headers.items())]
  File "aiohttp/_multidict.pyx", line 464, in aiohttp._multidict._ItemsView.__iter__ (aiohttp/_multidict.c:8990)
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

As far as I understand the question:

> How to serialize/deserialize Response, if possible, and if impossible,
>   what to do for caching result - there are some workaround ?

Answer (score 0):

`aiohttp` is not intended to be used as caching proxy -- thus `web.StreamResponse` and descendants are not serializable.

The idea of serializing stream response or websocket session is a bit awkward, isn't it? Perhaps I should add pickling support for multidicts through -- but I have no user request for it.

Anyway, I suggest caching not response but, say, page fragments or the whole rendered response body -- which requires more work but sounds like  robust solution.